# can not create yeoman project on my mac running OS X Yosemite 10.11.2 (angular-generator)

Tags: yeoman

can not create yeoman project on my mac running OS X Yosemite 10.11.2 (angular-generator)

> npm WARN EPEERINVALID gulp-karma@0.0.4 requires a peer of karma@>=0.10
>   <=0.13 but none was installed.
>       [10:29:09] Using gulpfile ~/Workspace/yeoman/mytodo/gulpfile.js
>       [10:29:09] Task 'wiredep' is not in your gulpfile
>       [10:29:09] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
>       ? Overwrite package.json? overwrite this and all others
>           force     package.json
>           create     .travis.yml
>       mytodo@ /Users/alan/Workspace/yeoman/mytodo
>       ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt@0.4.x
>       ├─┬ grunt-karma@0.12.1
>       │ └── lodash@3.10.1
>       ├─┬ gulp-imagemin@2.4.0
>       │ └─┬ imagemin@4.0.0
>       │   └─┬ imagemin-svgo@4.2.0
>       │     └─┬ svgo@0.6.1
>       │       └─┬ js-yaml@3.4.6
>       │         └─┬ argparse@1.0.3
>       │           └── lodash@3.10.1
>       ├─┬ gulp-jshint@1.12.0
>       │ └── lodash@3.10.1
>       ├─┬ gulp-sass@2.1.1
>       │ └─┬ node-sass@3.4.2
>       │   └─┬ sass-graph@2.0.1
>       │     └── lodash@3.10.1
>       ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jasmine-core@*
>       ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY karma@^0.13.0 || >= 0.14.0-rc.0
>       ├── karma-jasmine@0.3.6
>       ├─┬ karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.2.1
>       │ └── lodash@3.10.1
>       └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY phantomjs@>=1.9
>
> npm WARN EPEERINVALID gulp-karma@0.0.4 requires a peer of karma@>=0.10 <=0.13 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma-jasmine@0.3.6 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but none was installed.
>   npm WARN EPEERINVALID grunt-karma@0.12.1 requires a peer of grunt@0.4.x but none was installed.
>   npm WARN EPEERINVALID grunt-karma@0.12.1 requires a peer of karma@^0.13.0 || >= 0.14.0-rc.0 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.2.1 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.2.1 requires a peer of phantomjs@>=1.9 but none was installed.

use yeoman angular-generator,when I run '`gulp serve`',the console shows:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into problems when installing Yeoman on my mac as well. For me updating node/npm fixed the issues.